# Admob banner adjustment on Android ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

i have list view and i want to show ad banner in the bottom of this list view and also i have created space for this banner i.e android:paddingBottom="50dp", so i want to show ad on this 50dp space but now my ad showing on the above of this 50dp space i have 1 MainActivity.java and 2 xml file, first is activity_main.xml and second is single_row.xml. We know that there is no need to show java class because we set ad adjustment by xml.So i share my both xmls here and remember that i have relative layout not linear so there is no layout_weight option.
activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/bg"
   android:paddingBottom="50dp"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="aaaa111122223333"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My sigle_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img0"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:textColor="#FFFF00"
    android:textStyle="bold"
   />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `layout_above` for the `ListView` to place above the `AdView` Layout, so that you can see all the list items

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/layout"
```

Also, remove the bottom `padding` from the parent `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1):

`android:paddingBottom` is used to leave some space at the bottom inside the `View` not to specify some space for other `Views`.

Now, remove the following attribute from parent `RelativeLayout`

```
android:paddingBottom="50dp"
```

And set `50dp` to `android:layout_height` attribute for `com.google.ads.AdView` as below

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="aaaa111122223333"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hamid Shatu: i have applied your code but in this case my list view last item will be hidden behind the ad banner and last item will not be shown.

Comment: this should be...this the behave of `ListView`.

Comment: Is there any another way to fix it ?

Comment: I'm not seeing any other way unless you change your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative Container, inside that use `layout_above="@id/your_adview_id"` on your `listview`.

Add your `adView` below `ListView` and set its `visibility="gone"`.

In your java, when the add is loaded, set the visibility to visible as `adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

I hope this helps :)